# If PHP counter is equal to 4 items inside WordPress echo class not working correctly

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I am working with WordPress and Advanced custom fields. I have created a for each loop and everything works just fine. But I don't want posts with "draft" status to be displayed this works as well, but if the array length of the posts is equal or greater then 4 posts I want to display a different HTML class "col-sm-6" but this doesn't work.

Basically, if posts are Published and array length is equal to 4 change class else do nothing. But for some reason, it's not working how it should be.

Can someone help me out?

My code:

```
<?php
$posts = get_field('home_add_news');
$counter = 0;
if($posts):
?>

<section id="news">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <?php
            foreach( $posts as $post):
            $post_date = get_the_date( 'd M Y' );
            $post_img_url = get_the_post_thumbnail_url($post->ID, 'full');
            $post_categories = get_the_category( $post->ID );
            $post_category = $post_categories[0]->cat_name;
            $post_class = '';

            if(has_category('nieuws')):
                $post_class = 'news__block--image';
            elseif(has_category('project')):
                $post_class = 'news__block--primary';
            elseif(has_category('proces')):
                $post_class = 'news__block--secondary';
            elseif(has_category('tijdlijn')):
                $post_class = 'news__block--tertiary';
            else:
                $post_class = 'news__block--tertiary';
            endif;

            if ('publish' === $post->post_status):
            $counter++;
            ?>
            <div class="col-custom <?php if ($counter >= 4): echo 'col-sm-6'; endif; ?>">
            <article id="<?php echo get_the_ID(); ?>" class="news__block <?php echo $post_class; ?>" <?php if(!empty($post_img_url) && has_category('nieuws')): ?> style="background-image: url('<?php echo $post_img_url; ?>');" <?php endif; ?>>
                    <div class="news__container">
                        <header class="news__header">
                            <h3 class="news__pretitle"><?php echo $post_category; ?> <?php if(has_category('nieuws')): echo '- ' . $post_date; endif; ?></h3>
                            <h2 class="news__title"><?php echo $post->post_title; ?></h2>
                            <?php if($post->post_excerpt): ?>
                            <p class="news__message"><?php echo $post->post_excerpt; ?></p>
                            <?php endif; ?>
                        </header>
                        <a href="<?php echo get_post_permalink(); ?>" class="news__link">Lees meer</a>
                    </div>
                </article>
            </div>

            <?php endif; ?>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>

<?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: you already test `post_status` in the `if` then the first step is to remove the 2nd test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are trying to display the class `col-sm-6` for posts greater than 4.

There are a few things, you could do to make it work.

1. Remove the code which increments `$counter` just after `foreach` loop. We would do this in step 2 below.

```
            foreach( $posts as $post):
            //$counter++; This should be commented.
```

2. We should instead increment this counter inside the `if` block where you are checking for the status.

```
            if ('publish' === $post->post_status):

               //echo $counter;  //Comment this out
               $counter++;  //increment it here
            ?>
```

3. Last step is to make sure that when `$counter` is greater than or equal to 4 then display our class. As suggested by @Kaperto, you do not need to check for `draft` status here as you are already checking for the status above.

So take out the following line

```
<div class="col-custom <?php if ('draft' != $post->post_status && $counter == 4): echo 'col-sm-6'; endif; ?>">
```

and change it to

```
<div class="col-custom <?php if ($counter >= 4): echo 'col-sm-6'; endif; ?>">
```

Comment: I have made the changes but still not working. I have replaced my code can you take a look?

Comment: @Galanthus yes, the code looks good. May I know what exactly is not working. This should display class `col-sm-6` for post no. 4 and above.

Comment: Hi! If a post is set to "Draft" it still outputs 4 items from the array so there are always 4 items even if a post is set to Draft and rest "Public". When I have 4 public items the class should be "col-sm-6". But for some reason, the 4th item is only "col-sm-6". Can you help? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sorry that won't be possible unless you know that  number of posts  are greater than 4 before you begin the foreach loop.

Comment: I will try something else no problem thanks for the help anyways!